# Django and threading.local() quirks?

Tags: python, django, thread-safety, middleware

Recently I've started using threading.local() as way for some apis to store and access state for duration of request without having to access request object.

So lets say I have certain code:

```
_thread_local = threading.local()
_thread_local.theme = 'darkblues'
```

How long does that `_thread_local.theme` variable lasts? Do I have to manually unset it at the end of request in, say, custom middleware? Or it's deleted by Django automatically after it finishes processing request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will last as long as `threading.local()` lasts<strike>, which is the lifetime of the request</strike>.  Nothing special is required after that.  Django doesn't do much to manage state on thread locals, so things might stick around after the request is over.  Is this really a problem?  You would probably end up setting the value to whatever it needs to be in the next request.